# Archive multiple artifacts in multiple folders in jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to archive both the `target/surefire-reports` from my Maven project (easy), but in addition archive files that my project creates that are in the base workspace (csv report).  Do I do something like this: `target/surefire-reports/**/*, *.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are doing the right thing.

my syntax is **logs/**/*.exec,logs/**/***.log,obsQueue.txt,  and it works.

make sure you that those files really exist in the workspace.
note that all archive files , are relative to the workspace.

let me know if I can help with this issue.

Comment: Sometimes just a comma can make your life easier. Life does not always demand linux skills :P