# Archive multiple artifacts in multiple folders in jenkins Post-build Actions?

Tags: jenkins

I have a file in below location and I managed to attach it as an artifact.

```
AutomationFrameworkDemo\ExtentReprt\ExtentSummaryReport.html
```

I also have an another file  that I wish to attach in below location.

```
AutomationFrameworkDemo\test-output\testng-failed.xml
```

I tried to give the path with comma separated as per [Archive multiple artifacts in multiple folders in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842495/archive-multiple-artifacts-in-multiple-folders-in-jenkins) but I get below error. Any help or suggestion on this ?

[image]

Comment: Seems to suggest the file is not there. Navigate the workplace and verify presence. Refer to [archiveArtifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/), perhaps allowEmptyArchive?

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that either the file/folder does not exist or jenkins does not have permission to write in. Check:

1. Existence of the folder `AutomationFrameworkDemo/test-output` and the xml file within.
2. The permissions on the folder, the parent and xml file as its child.
3. Whether the file is created during the job run or not. (This one is unlikely to happen, as Jenkins has thrown error during form save)

Comment: Point 3 is correct, the file is created if by build is failed only . so even after the build fails  it won't attach when I gave like AutomationFrameworkDemo/ExtentReprt/ExtentSummaryReport.html,AutomationFrameworkDemo/test-output/testng-failed.xml

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva Then you need to change the flag of AllowEmptyArchive to true. Or you can add post actions in your declarative Pipeline so it will always creates the file. Syntax is : `post { success {` or `post { always {`